# Redux reducers as pure functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I always initialize dates in redux reducers doing this:

```
const initialState = {
  dateFilter: new Date()
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
// reducer code
}

export default reducer;
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way, because as I understand reducers must be pure functions and new Date is not pure. Maybe this is more a js question because I don't understand if the reducer function is pure here or not.

Comment: why do you think that this function is not pure? Cause right now in this snippet this function is empty, how do you know that this is pure or not?

Comment: I'm assuming that everything else is pure and I'm not doing any `new Date` inside the reducer code. The question is about that `initialState`. But ok, I think that param doesn't make the function impure

Comment: your initialState is only being created once and used as a fallback for the argument if it's not provided. your function is pure as long as you don't change the global state from your reducer and always return a new state instead of mutation the previous state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pure provided that you don't do something else within `// reducer code` :). Like for example calling to `new Date` again (as in the second example)

```js
const initialState = {
  dateFilter: new Date()
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    
    default: return state
  }
}

console.log(`Reducer is ${
  reducer(undefined, {type: '@@INIT'}) === reducer(undefined, {type: '@@INIT'})
  ? 'pure'
  : 'not pure'}`)
```

This one is not

```js
const initialState = () => ({
  dateFilter: new Date()
})

const reducer = (state = initialState(), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    
    default: return state
  }
}

console.log(`Reducer is ${
  reducer(undefined, {type: '@@INIT'}) === reducer(undefined, {type: '@@INIT'})
  ? 'pure'
  : 'not pure'}`)
```

**UPD**
As @spender has mentioned `initialState` has to be immutable. Which is quite hard to guarantee in javascript because objects and dates are both mutable by default. To guarantee immutability one could use

```
const initialState = Object.freeze({ // freeze the object
  dateFilter: Date.now() // use immutable number instead of Date instance
})
```

Also TLDR from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

Pure function is a function which output depends on the input and it does not perform any observable side-effects. Think of say addition `const add = (a, b) => a + b` `add(1, 2)` is always `3` and no missiles were launched. If functions are pure you could **safely**: cache results, reorder or delay calls, call function multiple times on the same arguments and such.

- `add(1, 2)` could be replaced with 3. If a function say counts how many times its been called it would be impossible.
- `add(add(1,2), add(2,3))` you could first do `add(1, 2)` then `add(2, 3)` or the other way around. If a function say logs to console it would be impossible.
- and so on.

Smoke test for a function to be pure is "same input yields same output".

Unfortunatelly (or fortunatelly :)) by default functions in js are not required to be pure and usually its hard to guarantee they are because javascript built-in objects are mutable by default.

Even the add function above could cause side-effects so you have to take purity definition with a grain of salt.

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b

const a = {
  _i: 1,
  valueOf() {
    console.log('Missiles launched')
    return this._i++;
  }
}

console.log(add(a, 1), add(a, 1))
```

Comment: Sorry but why ? Could you explain please?

Comment: The fact that you got an argument by performing side-effect does not make the function inpure. Imagine you have two random numbers (`a = Math.random(), b = Math.random()`). The fact they are somehow randomly generated  doesn't make say `const add = (a, b) => a + b` to be not pure

Comment: I'd argue that, in the no-parameter case, the function is only pure **if** `initialState` is guaranteed immutable.

Comment: Maybe I'm a newbie but I don't get the difference between a pure and no pure function(it's purely technical from my point of view), if @YuryTarabanko can explain this in his answer I would appreciate

Comment: @spender Right, but that would be quite hard in javascript. Even if you do `const initialState = Object.freeze({ dateFilter: new Date() })` one could still mutate the date. `const initialState = Object.freeze({ dateFilter: Date.now() })` would be a better option. But this seems like an overkill to me :)

Comment: @GrecoJonathan Pure function is a function which output depends on the input and it does not do perform any observable side-effects. Think of say addition. `add(1, 2)` is always 3 and no missles were launched. If functions are pure you could **safely**: cache results, reorder or delay calls, call function multiple times on the same arguments and such. Smoke test for a function to be pure is "same input yields same output". By default functions in js are not required to be pure and usually its hard to guarantee they are because javascript built-in objects are mutable by default.

Comment: whow! could you please immortalize that in your answer :) I will need that for a reminder